# drupal 8 views date range filter - 'is between' operator not inclusive for end date

Tags: datetime, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have an Event content type with a Date range field. I created a view of events and added an exposed filter for the Date Range field. I used the operator 'is between', so the user can enter a start date and end date to search between.

If the event starts on 1/1/11 at 9am and ends on 1/1/11 at 5pm, I want this event to show up when the user filters for events between 1/1/11 and 1/1/11.

But there are no results unless you change the end date to something greater than 1/1/11. I know this makes sense according to the 'is between' filter but I don't think it will be intuitive for users.

Can anyone help me with a way to make the end date inclusive, so it includes events on the end date specified??

I'm using the datetime_range module, and I've patched it with #60 at https://www.drupal.org/node/2786577 to enable date range filtering with views.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're going to need the [Views Date Filter Datetime Granularity Option](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2868014) patch (until it gets committed) as well as the change from [The Views integration Datetime Range fields should extend the views integration for regular Datetime fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2786577), which is now in Drupal core 8.6+.

For even better UX, see [Exposed views date filter with offset not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2982968)